# PHP set locale German not working in project

Tags: php, localization, locale

```
     $time = new DateTime('today 4 PM');

     $now = new DateTime('now');

     // check if current time is past 4 PM
          if ($now > $time) {
          $time = new DateTime('tomorrow 4 PM');
          }

     $diff = $time->diff($now);
```

the part I do not need to explain

after that I am checking  the day with

```
     $dw = date( "w");
     if ($dw == 6 || $dw == 0) {
```

and have a few if and else statements if its dw is 6 then it should increase the day +2 so if it is Friday it is Sunday

and now I am trying to print it out with an echo

```
     echo "Date ".$datetime->format('<b>l, d F</b>') . ";
```

it prints Sunday, 15 June but I am trying it to convert it to German. That don't really work so it still print it out in english. What I already check:
I already  add

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
```

and already check if the German local is installed and yes it is
and a few more... but nothing works...
and I thought about deleting locales to get only the German maybe that could work
and I thought about it I an array to define the days with the German name so 0 = Sunday but then I have to change everything

Comment: +1 from me, I'd always encourage ppl to use `DateTime` over any other date time mode/function and I would expect it to be able to use locales too without `::format()`.

Answer (score 6):

See the note in the manual on [`DateTime::format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php):

> This method does not use locales. All output is in English.

If you want to output other locales than English, you will have to use [`strftime()`](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strftime.php).

Comment: ah ok cool but how to set with strftime() today 4 PM, like above?

Comment: @ThePom See the manual, `l, d F` would be something like `%A, %d %B`.

Comment: it still prints the english version out I also add setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE"); again

Comment: @ThePom Then the locale is probably not installed, I get this from the command line: `$ php -r 'setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE"); echo strftime("%A, %d %B");'
Freitag, 13 Juni`

Comment: ok if I look at the server with putty I get Fr 13. Jun 17:15:37 CEST 2014 so thta is the Germany time but Magento have a time problem I think

Comment: @ThePom Maybe it's overwriting your locale settings.

Comment: ahh if I enter php -r 'setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE"); echo strftime("%A, %d %B") . "\n";' then I get the english ?? :)) there is something wrong

Comment: but if I  look at /etc/default/locale I get this 
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55580/discussion-between-thepom-and-jeroen).